# ¿Por qué no puedo instanciar una clase en otra?

Tags: c++, poo, clase, class, constructor

Tengo un problema al instanciar una clase en otra, puse un ejemplo básico para que sea más sencillo de entender.

Creo una clase (`class Primera_clase`), donde creo un atributo como entero y le pongo un constructor por defecto y otro que recibe un entero y modifica el atributo de la clase.

```
#include <iostream>

class Primera_clase{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        Primera_clase();
        Primera_clase(int n){
            num = num + n;
        }
};
```

Luego creo otra clase (`class Segunda_clase`), que tiene una variable de tipo `Primera_clase`. En el constructor por defecto de la clase `Segunda_clase` quiero llamar al otro constructor de `Segunda_clase` y me marca un error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Primera_clase.h"

class Segunda_clase{
    private:
        Primera_clase objeto_1;
    public:
        Segunda_clase(){
            objeto_1(2); //EN ESTA LINEA MARCA ERROR
        }
};
```

Este es el error que me marca:

> *include\Segunda_clase.h|9|error: no match for call to '(Primera_clase) (int)'|***

Esta es la función principal

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Segunda_clase.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

*¿Cual es el problema?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera de llamar a la primera clase para crear la instancia es distinta

```
objeto_1(2);
```

se debe cambiar a:

```
objeto_1 = Primera_clase(2);
```

El constructor de la clase se llama por su nombre, y su resultado sera la instancia (objeto), en este caso `objeto_1`

```
class Primera_clase{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        Primera_clase();
        Primera_clase(int n){
            num = num + n;
        }
};

class Segunda_clase{
    private:
        Primera_clase objeto_1;
    public:
        Segunda_clase(){
            objeto_1 = Primera_clase(2); //corregido
        }
};
```